# How to handle multiple touch events in same activity on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to set some distincts touch interactions in the same screen in a jetpack compose project. However, setting a `pointerFilter` modifier to the main screen container automatically overrides any other clickable composable inside it. See the code below for a example:

```
    setContent {
        val context = LocalContext.current //only to be used in toasts
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Gray)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .pointerInteropFilter {
                    if (it.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Toast
                            .makeText(context, "ENTIRE SCREEN RELEASED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                    true
                }
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON CLICKED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }) {
                Text(text = "BUTTON")
            }
        }
    }
```

Doing this basically make that any clickable composable doesn't work, such the example `Button`. Also, note that I'm considering the `Box` as my "screen", once I set it to fill max size (is this the best way to handle clicks for the screen in jetpack compose?).

Then, how to make even entire screen (`Box`?) and its children clickable and handle its events?

Comment: Perhaps you can achieve what you want with `Modifier.pointerInput{}`. pointerInteropFilter is supposed to be used for very low level motion events.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, ```pointerInput``` worked well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks too @Rafsanjani for his insight of using the Modifier.pointerInput{}.

To achieve a solution to handle events to multiple composables I just added the modifers like as follows:

```
setContent {
    val context = LocalContext.current //only to be used in toasts
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(key1 = "someStringKey?") {
                detectTapGestures(onPress = {
                    if (tryAwaitRelease()) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "MAIN SCREEN RELEASED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                })
            }
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON CLICKED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }) {
            Text(text = "BUTTON")
        }
    }
}
```

This basically handles different events for the `Box` (the composable that fills max size) and a button.